# Why is collision not firing when after player collects target?

Tags: javascript

I created a little JavaScript game wherein a player can use their mouse to move a circle around the screen, however, I am having an issue where it seems the collision is not firing appropriately. If I hit an obstacle without collecting any of the target blocks everything fires correctly, but if I collect any before hitting one the header says "Game over", but the Restart button does not spawn, and the user can keep playing.
I attached all the codes directly.

```js
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
var dead = false;

/* Make a game. */
var game = document.createElement('div');
game.style.width = '100%';
game.style.height = '100%';
game.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
game.style.color = '#fff';
game.style.fontFamily = 'monospace';
game.style.fontSize = '20px';
game.style.textAlign = 'center';
game.style.paddingTop = '50px';
game.innerHTML = '<div id="game-title">Dodge the Particles! </div><p style="font-size: small;">(But eat the pink ones!)</p><div id="game-content"></div>';
document.body.appendChild(game);

/* Add a player to the game. */
var player = document.createElement('div');
player.style.width = '20px';
player.style.height = '20px';
player.style.backgroundColor = '#00f';
player.style.position = 'absolute';
player.style.left = '50%';
player.style.top = '50%';
player.style.borderRadius = '10px';
player.style.marginLeft = '-10px';
player.style.marginTop = '-10px';
document.getElementById('game-content').appendChild(player);

/* Now make it constantly move towards the mouse. */
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;
};
var playerX = 0;
var playerY = 0;
var playerSpeed = 3;
var playerMove = function() {
  var dx = mouseX - playerX;
  var dy = mouseY - playerY;
  var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  if (dist > playerSpeed) {
    dx *= playerSpeed / dist;
    dy *= playerSpeed / dist;
  }
  playerX += dx;
  playerY += dy;
  player.style.left = playerX + 'px';
  player.style.top = playerY + 'px';
};
setInterval(playerMove, 10);

/* Now throw small objects across the screen every second. These objects should be thrown from random locations around the sides of the screen. 

The objects are supposed to disappear after they have existed for 6 seconds. */
var objects = [];
var objectSpeed = 5;
var objectSize = 10;
var objectLifetime = 6000;
var objectSpawn = function() {
  var object = document.createElement('div');
  object.style.width = objectSize + 'px';
  object.style.height = objectSize + 'px';
  object.style.backgroundColor = '#0f0';
  object.style.position = 'absolute';
  object.style.left = '50%';
  object.style.top = '50%';
  object.style.marginLeft = '-' + (objectSize / 2) + 'px';
  object.style.marginTop = '-' + (objectSize / 2) + 'px';
  document.getElementById('game-content').appendChild(object);
  var side = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  if (side === 0) {
    x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
    y = 0;
  } else if (side === 1) {
    x = window.innerWidth;
    y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
  } else if (side === 2) {
    x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
    y = window.innerHeight;
  } else if (side === 3) {
    x = 0;
    y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
  }
  var dx = playerX - x;
  var dy = playerY - y;
  var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  dx *= objectSpeed / dist;
  dy *= objectSpeed / dist;
  var objectMove = function() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    object.style.left = x + 'px';
    object.style.top = y + 'px';
  };
  var objectRemove = function() {
    document.getElementById('game-content').removeChild(object);
    clearInterval(objectMoveInterval);
  };
  var objectMoveInterval = setInterval(objectMove, 10);
  setTimeout(objectRemove, objectLifetime);
  objects.push(object);
};
setInterval(objectSpawn, 1000);
/* Throw them more frequently. */
clearInterval(objectSpawnInterval);
var objectSpawnInterval = setInterval(objectSpawn, 500);


var playerSize = 20;
var playerCollision = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var object = objects[i];
    var x = parseInt(object.style.left);
    var y = parseInt(object.style.top);
    var dx = playerX - x;
    var dy = playerY - y;
    var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    if (dist < playerSize / 2 + objectSize / 2) {
      gameOver();
    }
  }
};
setInterval(playerCollision, 10);

/* This code generates a pink square on the map. Every time the player collides with the pink square, it creates a new one in a new location, and update the player's score. */
var score = 0;
var scoreElement = document.createElement('div');
scoreElement.style.position = 'absolute';
scoreElement.style.left = '0px';
scoreElement.style.top = '20px';
scoreElement.style.width = '100%';
scoreElement.style.textAlign = 'center';
scoreElement.innerHTML = 'Score: ' + score;
document.getElementById('game-content').appendChild(scoreElement);
var scoreObject = document.createElement('div');
scoreObject.style.width = objectSize + 'px';
scoreObject.style.height = objectSize + 'px';
scoreObject.style.backgroundColor = '#f0f';
scoreObject.style.position = 'absolute';
scoreObject.style.left = '50%';
scoreObject.style.top = '50%';
scoreObject.style.marginLeft = '-' + (objectSize / 2) + 'px';
scoreObject.style.marginTop = '-' + (objectSize / 2) + 'px';
document.getElementById('game-content').appendChild(scoreObject);
var scoreObjectX = 0;
var scoreObjectY = 0;
var scoreObjectMove = function() {
  scoreObjectX = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  scoreObjectY = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
  scoreObject.style.left = scoreObjectX + 'px';
  scoreObject.style.top = scoreObjectY + 'px';
};
scoreObjectMove();
var scoreObjectCollision = function() {
  var dx = playerX - scoreObjectX;
  var dy = playerY - scoreObjectY;
  var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  if (dist < playerSize / 2 + objectSize / 2) {
    score++;
    scoreElement.innerHTML = 'Score: ' + score;
    scoreObjectMove();
  }
};
setInterval(scoreObjectCollision, 10);

/* If the player collides with an obstacle, stop moving the player, hide the player, and stop counting points. */
var playerMoveInterval = setInterval(playerMove, 10);
var playerCollisionInterval = setInterval(playerCollision, 10);
var playerScoreInterval = setInterval(scoreObjectCollision, 10);
var playerHide = function() {
  player.style.display = 'none';
  clearInterval(playerMoveInterval);
  clearInterval(playerCollisionInterval);
  clearInterval(playerScoreInterval);
  dead = true;
};

/* Create a game over function to run when the player dies. */
var gameOver = function() {
    document.getElementById('game-title').innerHTML = 'Game Over';
    clearInterval(objectSpawnInterval);
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById('game-content').removeChild(objects[i]);
    }
    objects = [];
    playerHide();
    scoreObject.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('game-content').appendChild(restartButton);
  };

/* When the player dies, show a restart button in the middle of the page. */
var restartButton = document.createElement('div');
restartButton.style.width = '100px';
restartButton.style.height = '50px';
restartButton.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
restartButton.style.color = '#000';
restartButton.style.position = 'absolute';
restartButton.style.zIndex = '1';
restartButton.style.left = '50%';
restartButton.style.top = '50%';
restartButton.style.marginLeft = '-50px';
restartButton.style.marginTop = '-25px';
restartButton.style.textAlign = 'center';
restartButton.style.lineHeight = '50px';
restartButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';
restartButton.innerHTML = 'Restart';
restartButton.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('game-title').innerHTML = 'Dodge the Particles! ';
  player.style.display = 'block';
  scoreObject.style.display = 'block';
  playerMoveInterval = setInterval(playerMove, 10);
  playerCollisionInterval = setInterval(playerCollision, 10);
  playerScoreInterval = setInterval(scoreObjectCollision, 10);
  score = 0;
  scoreElement.innerHTML = 'Score: ' + score;
  document.getElementById('game-content').removeChild(restartButton);
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your `gameOver` function attempts to remove all the obstacle objects in the array `objects[]` by calling `removeChild(objects[i])`, but these objects may have already been removed since they have a lifetime of 6 seconds (removed in `objectRemove`). Since they are no longer child nodes of the document, that call to `removeChild` fails with an error.

The restart button is created at the end of the `gameOver` function, but the function fails to get there since execution stops at the error. I'd suggest being more careful with how you're cleaning up these obstacle objects. You could remove it from the `objects` array at the same time that you call `removeChild` in `objectRemove`, for one. Then you wouldn't encounter it again in your `gameOver` function and trip that error.